# Is checking rows affected count after database action (insert, update, delete) overkill?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Lately in apps I've been developing I have been checking the number of rows affected by an insert, update, delete to the database and logging an an error if the number is unexpected.  For example on a simple insert, update, or delete of one row if any number of rows other than one is returned from an ExecuteNonQuery() call, I will consider that an error and log it.  Also, I realize now as I type this that I do not even try to rollback the transaction if that happens, which is not the best practice and should definitely be addressed.  Anyways, here's code to illustrate what I mean:

I'll have a data layer function that makes the call to the db:

```
public static int DLInsert(Person person)
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("dbConnString");

    using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.Insert_Person"))
    {
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@FirstName", DbType.Byte, person.FirstName);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@LastName", DbType.String, person.LastName);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Address", DbType.Boolean, person.Address);

        return db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
    }
}
```

Then a business layer call to the data layer function:

```
public static bool BLInsert(Person person)
{
    if (DLInsert(campusRating) != 1)
    {
        // log exception
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And in the code-behind or view (I do both webforms and mvc projects):

```
if (BLInsert(person))
{
    // carry on as normal with whatever other code after successful insert
}
else
{
    // throw an exception that directs the user to one of my custom error pages
}
```

The more I use this type of code, the more I feel like it is overkill.  Especially in the code-behind/view.  Is there any legitimate reason to think a simple insert, update, or delete wouldn't actually modify the correct number of rows in the database?  Is it more plausible to only worry about catching an actual SqlException and then handling that, instead of doing the monotonous check for rows affected every time?

Thanks.  Hope you all can help me out.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks everyone for taking the time to answer.  I still haven't 100% decided what setup I will use going forward, but here's what I have taken away from all of your responses.

- Trust the DB and .Net libraries to handle a query and do their job as they were designed to do.
- Use transactions in my stored procedures to rollback the query on any errors and potentially use `raiseerror` to throw those exceptions back to the .Net code as a SqlException, which could handle these errors with a try/catch.  This approach would replace the problematic return code checking.

Would there be any issue with the second bullet point that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the question becomes, "Why are you checking this?"  If it's just because you don't trust the database to perform the query, then it's probably overkill.  However, there *could* exist a logical reason to perform this check.

For example, I worked at a company once where this method was employed to check for concurrency errors.  When a record was fetched from the database to be edited in the application, it would come with a `LastModified` timestamp.  Then the standard CRUD operations in the data access layer would include a `WHERE LastMotified=@LastModified` clause when doing an `UPDATE` and check the record modified count.  If no record was updated, it would assume a concurrency error had occurred.

I felt it was kind of sloppy for concurrency checking (especially the part about assuming the nature of the error), but it got the job done for the business.

What concerns me more in your example is the structure of how this is being accomplished.  The `1` or `0` being returned from the data access code is a "magic number."  That should be avoided.  It's leaking an implementation detail from the data access code into the business logic code.  If you do want to keep using this check, I'd recommend moving the check into the data access code and throwing an exception if it fails.  In general, return codes should be avoided.

**Edit:** I just noticed a potentially harmful bug in your code as well, related to my last point above.  What if *more than one* record is changed?  It *probably* won't happen on an `INSERT`, but could easily happen on an `UPDATE`.  Other parts of the code might assume that `!= 1` means no record was changed.  That could make debugging very problematic :)

Comment: Upvoted for the comment about return codes. They are evil. I work with two developers on different projects, and one uses 1 as success, the other uses 1 as failure. Messy messy stuff.

Comment: @BrendonDugan: Indeed, there's just no need for return codes these days, at least not in the .NET world.  Exceptions are perfectly valid exit paths for methods and are designed to carry useful information about errors.  The closest thing to a return code that would make sense, I think, is the idea of a common return type (some sort of generic `IResponse`) for similarly-structured or auto-generated services.  It could contain something like a `Success` flag and/or an `Errors` collection.

Comment: I see your point about return codes and the != 1.  I think I just didn't trust the DB, so these extra checks may indeed be overkill.

Comment: @ryanulit: In that case, if you just don't trust the DB, how can you trust the records-modified result coming back? :)

Comment: @David, I typically return some type of struct which contains a Success flag (bool), an Error String, and then whatever other data needs to be returned.

Comment: Touché @David, never thought about that.

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand, most of the time everything should behave the way you expect, and on those times the additional checks don't add anything to your application. On the other hand, if something does go wrong, not knowing about it means that the problem may become quite large before you notice it. In my opinion, the little bit of additional protection is worth the little bit of extra effort, especially if you implement a rollback on failure. It's kinda like an airbag in your car... it doesn't really serve a purpose if you never crash, but if you do it could save your life.

Answer (score 1):

I've always prefered to `raiserror` in my sproc and handle exceptions rather than counting.  This way, if you update a sproc to do something else, like logging/auditing, you don't have to worry about keeping the row counts in check.

Though if you like the second check in your code or would prefer not to deal with exceptions/`raiserror`, I've seen teams return 0 on successful sproc executions for every sproc in the db, and return another number otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely overkill. You should trust that your core platform (.Net libraries, Sql Server) work correctly -you shouldn't be worrying about that.

Now, there are some related instances where you might want to test, like if transactions are correctly rolled back, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If there's is a need for that check, why not do that check within the database itself? You save yourself from doing a round trip and it's done at a more 'centralized' stage - If you check in the database, you can be assured it's being applied consistently from any application that hits that database. Whereas if you put the logic in the UI, then you need to make sure that any UI application that hits that particular database applies the correct logic and does it consistently.